# deploy ssis 2012 packages on 2008r2 server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, ssis

We've developed SSIS packages on ssis 2012, but now upon deployment, we need to deploy these to sql server 2008. I've been searching but haven't found a solution to do this. 
Is this even possible and what tools do I need to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot run SSIS package on a release that is below the developed level of the package, so it is not possible to deploy from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008 since SSIS packages are not backwards compatible.

This the SSIS engine issue.

See more here: [Interoperability and Coexistence (Integration Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522577.aspx)

From the documentation:

> On an instance of SQL Server 2014, you can import packages from an
>   instance of SQL Server 2005 or from an instance of SQL Server 2008,
>   but you cannot export packages to an instance of SQL Server 2005 or to
>   an instance of SQL Server 2008.
>
> On an instance of SQL Server 2005 or an instance of SQL Server 2008,
>   you cannot import packages from, nor export packages to, an instance
>   of SQL Server 2014.

Same goes for SQL Server 2012 compatibility with older versions

Hope this helps